# Using serial port of Moxa UC-8200 for communication using java JSSC library

Tags: java, arm, serial-port, jssc

I have Moxa computer that runs Debian 9 on armv7 CPU.

I tried running Java application on it that uses *JSSC* library for accessing serial port and communicating via it. At first I had problem with the app throwing exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/ubuntu/.jssc/linux/libjSSC-2.6_armhf.so: /home/ubuntu/.jssc/linux/libjSSC-2.6_armhf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I solved that problem by running the app using `sudo java -D.java.library.path=".:/lib/gnueabihf" -jar HelloSerial-1.0.0.jar` command, which will make java use hard float instead of soft float library, and that stopped the app from crashing.

Now I have problem that my app does not see any serial port at all. When I try to list all ports available, I get an empty list. I am simply using `SerialPortList.getCommPorts()` method, but it returns an empty list.

My question would be if anyone knows whether the *JSSC* library can work on a device that has arm architecture CPU, and that actually sees its serial ports as USB-to-serial ports?